# Is this a sensible way to programatically replace content on a SharePoint Page?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, content-editor, webpartpage

I have broken up a humongous page into several "bite-size" chunks. I want to present them, one at a time, to the user. After one page, they click an HTML button ("Next") and the previous Web Part or Content Editor Web Part is replaced by the next one.

From [this page](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-adding-web-parts-rich-content-sharepoint-2010/), I came up with some pseudcode (I don't know if there really is a SPLimitedWebPartManager.RemoveWebPart() method that I can call, as pseudocoded below, or how to get a reference to the currently (about-to-be-replaced) [Content Editor] Web Part, but this is the basic idea:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://~"))
{
    SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
    SPFile page = web.GetFile("Pages/Web_Form_Post_Travel_Expense.aspx");
    page.CheckOut();

    using (SPLimitedWebPartManager wpmgr = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared))
    {
        XmlElement d = new XmlDocument().CreateElement("div");
        d.InnerText = get
        ContentEditorWebPart cewp = new ContentEditorWebPart
        {
            Content = d
        };
        ContentEditorWebPart currentCEWP = ?;
        wpmgr.RemoveWebPart(currentCEWP);
        wpmgr.AddWebPart(cewp, "Header", 0);
    }

    page.CheckIn(String.Empty);
}
```

Does this make sense? It seems kludgy or even downright weird to me, to be checking out the page, changing it, and checking it back in.

The only other thing I can think of at the moment is to put the entire shebang into one Web Part, but keep sections 2-6 hidden at first, and then successively show one segment (after hiding the previous one). IOW, this type of procedure:

```
First Section shows
All others hidden

User selects "Next" button

First section is hidden
Second section shows, while all others remain hidden.

etc.
```

Actually, both ideas seem at least a little wonky to me. Is one approach preferable, or is there a third way I haven't thought of that would be better than both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are **CheckOut()** and **CheckIn(string value)** for? Is that the question?

I looked at the [Microsoft.SharePoint namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint) and the [SPSite class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite), but nothing appeared to be defined.

My best guess is this is a way of placing a lock on a document while it is opened by another person.

See the following supporting items:

- [SPFile.SPCheckOutStatus enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.spcheckoutstatus?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [SPFile.SPCheckOutType enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.spcheckouttype)
- [SPFileCheckOutExceptionType enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfilecheckoutexceptiontype)
- [SPFile.SPLockType enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.splocktype)

That way, if you have [Mark Twain](http://twaincentral.azurewebsites.net/#chap1) checked out to edit, no one else can check that out to edit.

If, on the other hand, you simply want to view the contents, you could check out a section, read it all in to a StringBuilder, check the contents back in to SharePoint, and then display the text as you need it.

Comment: I'm surprised no one else took the time to look it over. Nobody even voted on the question. Oh well.

Comment: Sharepoint is a bit of a ghost town; as usual, my professional coding (Sharepoint) and my personal coding (Meteor) are quite different, but both are currently relatively "fringy" (that's not a real word, so who knows what the spelling should be). Sharepoint may be waning; Meteor is waxing, though.